# my http request won't work, angular 2

Tags: http, angular2-routing

I am using a MEAN stack

I have successfully served a simple JSON object {"message":"hello"} sent with an express get and res.send function that appears in my web browser if I go to the route

also on my angular 2 front end I have an http.request() that works fine if I put a JSON test api url but if I put my route url to my simple JSON then I don't get a response. Any idea what the reason might be?

my angular 2 component.ts:

```
makeRequest(): void {
    this.loading = true;
    this.http.request('myurl/members')
    .subscribe((res: Response) => {
    this.data = res.json();
    this.loading = false;
    });
  }
```

my server.js express:

```
// Get dependencies
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('sangha',['members']);
const app = express();

// Parsers for POST data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Point static path to dist
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

// Set port
const port ='80';
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */
const server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`running on port ${port}`));


/*db methods
db.members.insert({"firstname":"Josh"});
db.members.findAndModify({
  query: {lastname: ''},
  update: {$set: {firstname: ''}},
  new: true
}, function (err, doc, lastErrorObject){
  //?
});
db.members.find(function(err,docs){
  console.log("members collection: "+docs;
});
*/

/*submit on login page, first check the username doesn't already exists, then 
db.members.insert*/
//app.post('/members',function(req,res)

app.get('/members',function(req,res){
  res.send({"message":"hello"});
});

//this catch all must come after all route definitions
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: what does your code look like? update it to the post

Comment: ok, I have added the code